# Cant define coordinate and velocities off of seperate file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, physics

I'm trying to build a simulation of particle movements using python. I have used someone else's code to make sure I have matplotlib, numpy, math, and scipy all correctly installed. In the code I'm working on I have created a separate file for the position, velocity, and acceleration of the particles that is then read by the master code. My problem is that I keep getting an error message saying that `'x' is not defined`. I'm lost because my section of code that recalls those values from the separate file is something that a grad student helped me with, and his runs perfectly well.

```py
for i in particleinfo:
    count = 0
    while count < NumParticles:    
        line = particleinfo[count]
        values = line.split(' ')
        x = float(values[0])
        y = float(values[1])
        z = float(values[2])
        vx = float(values[3])
        vy = float(values[4])
        vz = float(values[5])
        ax = float(values[6])
        ay = float(values[7])
        az = float(values[8])
        count = count+1

print(x)
```

Comment: In this piece of code the indentation is incorrect, please copy the exact code that results in an error. Also, if we correct intuitively the indentation here, for example if `NumParticles` is 0, you will never enter the `while` loop and `x` will never be defined

Comment: I directly copy/pasted that. Maybe I didn't do it right, but if I did copy it over correctly then that may explain why it's not working. Are you saying that I also should go ahead and get rid of the while loop on it?

Comment: No, I'm saying that running this piece of code will give you an indentation error, which is not what you are saying in your post.  I think that all the lines are part of the `for` loop, and thus should be indented. Also the `print(x)` is out of the code section of your post. There might have been a problem when you entered it here, so please verify that the indentation is the same as in your code, and otherwise correct it.

Comment: I made an attempt to correct the indentation, I'll leave it to you to confirm if it is now consistent with the indentation in your code.